# Como excluir um certo grupo da expressão regular

Tags: regex

Estou com um arquivo fiscal que vem com a seguinte informação na linha:

```
Ex:. OCF|DINHEIRO|160.12|12
```

Para corrigir ele tenho que apagar uma parte, e o certo seria:

```
OCF|DINHEIRO|160.12
```

Então comecei a fazer uma expressão regular no notepad++;
Na qual eu consigo localizar exatamente o que eu quero buscar.
A expressão é essa:

```
(^OCF\|)(\w*\|)(\d*.\d*)
```

Agora preciso saber como substituir todos para que seja gerado o valor que eu espero:

```
OCF|DINHEIRO|160.12
```

Comment: Fará isso pelo editor de texto ou em alguma linguagem de programação?

Comment: O AP utiliza Notepad++, então é somente utilizar esta Expressão Regular com Ctrl+F, depois ir na aba Substituir, Inserir a expressão na caixa Localizar, alterar o modo de busca para Expressão Regular e substituir todos.

Answer (score 8):

A ideia é procurar pelo padrão que deseja remover. Pelo que entendi você quer remover o `|12` ao final do texto, ou seja, o padrão que procura é `|número`

A minha expressão se baseia no seguinte:

- `\|`procure por um barra, é necessário o escape porque a barra no `regex` tem a função de `OU`
- `\d+` atalho para procurar por números de forma gulosa.
- `$` borda que procura ao fim de uma string.

## Funcionando

```js
let texto = 'OCF|DINHEIRO|160.12|12';
let expressao = /\|\d+$/;
console.log(texto.replace(texto.match(expressao),''));
```

## [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2CMHYo/1)

Answer (score 7):

Caso a expressão seja utilizada no editor *Notepad++*, faça como o *Marconi* disse.

Acesse o atalho `CTRL+H` e no campo *Encontrar o quê?* coloque a expressão `\|\d+$` e clique em *Substituir Tudo*.

[image: Notepad++]

Para utilizar a expressão que você escreveu, você terá que adicionar no final `\|\d+` e no campo *Substituir com:* coloque `\1\2\3` que é referente aos grupos.

[image: Notepad++]

Comment: Ficou bacana demais os `gif's`. :D +1